# How do I save the settings of this script in a cookie and make it dependend of another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I'm trying to make a button, to switch the site background once clicked. And of course the setting needs to be saved in a cookie, for it to stick.

How can I combine the two scripts, so that once the button is clicked, it stays switched, with the background? Or is dependend on the body class 'clicked'?

I found a way to switch and save the background in a cookie:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var body_class = $.cookie('body_class');
if(body_class) {
    $('body').attr('class', body_class);
}
$("#switch").click(function() {
    $("body").toggleClass('clicked');
    $.cookie('body_class', $('body').attr('class'));
});
```

});

And the button is switched from switch_on.png to switch_off.png with this:

```
$(function(){
$(".toggle-swap").click(function() {
if ($(this).attr("class") == "toggle-swap") {
  this.src = this.src.replace("switch_on.png","switch_off.png");
} else {
  this.src = this.src.replace("switch_off.png","switch_on.png");
}
$(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

});

My button:

```
<div id="switch"><a href="#"><img class="toggle-swap" src="../img/switch_on.png" alt=""></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd combine that into one function, e.g. like this:

```
$(function() {
    // Create a variable for the current state
    var body_class;

    // Cache some elements
    var $body = $('body'), $switch = $('.toggle-swap');

    // Define a function that toggles background + button
    var toggleBodyClass = function(event) {
        // Toggle the images
        if (body_class) {
            $switch[0].src = $switch[0].src.replace("switch_off.png","switch_on.png");
            body_class = '';
        } else {
            $switch[0].src = $switch[0].src.replace("switch_on.png","switch_off.png");
            body_class = 'clicked';
        }

        // Toggle some css classes (body + button)
        $body.toggleClass('clicked');
        $switch.toggleClass('on');

        // Update the cookie
        $.cookie('body_class', body_class);

        // Prevent the browsers default behavior
        if (event) event.preventDefault();
    };

    // Set the initial state
    if ($.cookie('body_class')) {
        toggleBodyClass();
    }

    // Bind the event handler
    $switch.click(toggleBodyClass);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work. Neither the body nor the button is doing anything. There must be something wrong..

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Used the wrong selector at one point. Please try again! (works very well in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pnRM3/)

Comment: `$.cookie` is not automatically included in jQuery. You'll have to reference a jQuery-plugin.

Comment: It kinda works. You may try it: test.unleashedart.com (that lil switch on the bottom right) When I first click it, it changes the background, but not the switch, but on the second click, both are changed. And sometimes the switch changes back, when going to another page, even though the background doesn't. Strange.
Also, I don't change the appearance of the switch image by css, but solely by changing the image. 
Btw, the site is still WIP, so don't worry if parts are not quiet right yet.

Comment: I think it's only these lines: `$switch[0].src = $switch[0].src.replace("switch_on.png","switch_off.png");` that are still wrong - you simply need to swap them, I've updated the above code to reflect that.

Comment: Great, seem to work just fine now.
One last thing: could you enlighten me, why the brwoser sometimes seems to forget the cookie, when switching between pages. Is there a way to set the cookie not only for session but for ever?

Comment: The reason for that is that cookies are domain-bound, i.e. if you visit the page by typing http://test.unleashedart.com in your browser's address bar, the cookie is associated with this exact domain. But if you click the logo on the upper left, you will get redirected to http://www.test.unleashedart.com - since the browser considers that a different domain, the cookie will not be delivered and therefore, the default background is shown.

Comment: So, if I link the logo to test.unleashedart.com instead of www.test.unleashedart.com it will work? Or how do I fix that?

Comment: Yes, you can either make sure that the domain will always be the same (with or without the `www.`) - or you can specify the basedomain when writing the cookie, to make the browser deliver cookies for that domain, and all subdomains: `$.cookie('body_class', body_class, {path:'/', domain:'.unleashedart.com'});`